# Polars unwrap one-element lists in all columns

Tags: python, python-polars

Say I have this:

```
df = polars.DataFrame(dict(
  j=[[1], [2], [3]],
  k=[[1, 1], [2], [3]],
  ))

 j (list[i64])  k (list[i64])
 [1]            [1, 1]
 [2]            [2]
 [3]            [3]
shape: (3, 2)
```

All lists in `j` have one element, while `k` has at least one list that has more than one element.

I'd like to unwrap all one-element lists across all columns, i.e. get this:

```
dfj = polars.DataFrame(dict(
  j=[1, 2, 3],
  k=[[1, 1], [2], [3]],
  ))

j (i64)  k (list[i64])
 1        [1, 1]
 2        [2]
 3        [3]
shape: (3, 2)
```

I've tried this:

```
dfj = (df
  .with_columns(
    polars
      .when(polars.col(col).list.lengths().max() == 1)
      .then(polars.col(col).list.first())
      .otherwise(polars.col(col))
    for col in df.columns
    )
  )
```

but it results in:

```
exceptions.ArrowErrorException: NotYetImplemented("Casting from Int64 to LargeList(Field { name: \"item\", data_type: Int64, is_nullable: true, metadata: {} }) not supported")
```

Any idea why this is not working? Also, is there a way to do what I'm after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is trying to produce `i64` or `list[i64]` which is not compatible.

You essentially want to replace the whole column:

```
df.with_columns(
   col.list.first() for col in df 
   if col.list.lengths().max() == 1
)
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ j   ┆ k         │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [1, 1]    │
│ 2   ┆ [2]       │
│ 3   ┆ [3]       │
└─────┴───────────┘
```